# Maven + Checkstyle: fail build if more violations are introduced?

Tags: maven, checkstyle

Having a build fail because a coding standard is violated is nice. However, when introducing checkstyle to a new project, there might be a lot of violations.

Instead of adding one and one rule, does anyone know of a (preferably simple) way of setting up something that will fail the build only if *more* warnings are introduced than were there before?

Comment: That requires the plugin to store historical information (in source control? or in target dir?), so I doubt you will not find something ready-made. I suggest you disable the check style build validation & put your project on sonar and monitor the quality manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. But as a workaround you can specify [maxAllowedViolations](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#maxAllowedViolations) (and maybe reduce this number manually with every check-in).

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Perfection is not required in this case.